# Can you display multiple coordinate system at the same time?

Tags: coordinates

I saw something familiar on [wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blender3d_NormalKoordinates.jpg) .

I need to display 5 coordinate systems at the same time but Blender only shows 1 coordinate system for the active object/vertex etc.

Comment: Not in the interface, no. The image on wikipedia was probably made by using duplifaces or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, I just modeled 5 objects as "coordinate systems" instead and then placed them